# bash moving multiple lines at the end of file

Tags: bash

I have a sample file with the following contents:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

What I need to do in `bash` is this:

1. I have a variable that defines how many lines I want to operate with
   ... for ex: ***numberoflines***=3
2. I need to retrieve into an array the first "***$numberoflines***" from the
   file above.
3. At the end I will need to move those "***$numberoflines***" in the same
   order to the end of the file.

So in my example (***numberoflines***=3) the file becomes:

```
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I need the code for points 2 and 3 using the ***numberoflines*** variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "need" to use an array?  This seems like a homework question.  The "go ahead and delete it" sounds even more that way.  If it's not, here's a way to do it without an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=3
file=/path/to/file
{ sed "1,${lines}d" < "$file"; head -n "$lines" "$file"; }
```

That deletes the first "lines" lines first, then the second one prints the first "lines" lines.

If this is homework :) and you really need to use an array, you just need to figure out how many elements are in the array, print everything from "lines+1" to the end, then print from 0 to "lines".  Or just read the file line-by-line, storing lines until you get to $lines.  After you've stored $lines lines, switch to printing rather than storing.  Then print out the array.  If I were doing this for real, that second way is how I'd do it.